# Mongodb find and limit by top 10 for each key

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Basically I have a web application that I'm building that will store scores grouped by a specific key ("Class"). "Class" can be 9A,9B,9C,9D, and the full document will be something akin to:

```
{
  "Class": "9A",
  "Course": "XX",
  "Category": "Acat",
  "Score": xxxx // integer
}
```

Basically I only want to retrieve the top 10 results for each class / course, and I'm not sure what the best solution here will be. Atm I have a couple methods I can think of, but neither seem like good practice to me:

- Using the async module or promises (Q.all), perform one query for each class in parallel.
- Select all the results, and limit it in a loop, then send the data once I have 10 results for each.

Option A seems better of the two, but not ideal. There could not be a better solution, but figured I'd look and see if there is one.

Cheers!

Comment: We can do this but the one question. Your criteria is both course and class or just class?

Comment: I'd prefer being able to query vs both to avoid having to run parallel queries.

Comment: I mean to say you want separate results  for course and class or both are one criteria ?

Comment: Course and class separate criteria or its one criteria together?

Comment: Ah, my apologies - both are separate criterias. So I'd want the top for each class and course (so if there are 4 classes and 2 courses, I'd want 8x10rows) if that makes sense?

Comment: if they are separate then shouldn't it be rather 6 * 10?

Comment: Separate but grouped? Wording is hard today.. Basically I'd want returned:
{class: "9A", course: "Math 1", "Score": [], class: "9A", course: "Math 2": "Score": []} etc etc